# Talend: condiitonally map String to boolean in tMap

Tags: java, boolean, talend

I have an Excel containing categories of company. In my dataset I want to add a boolean column telling if the categories is a start up or not.

#### Expected result mapping

Columns and data types:

- `Categorie` of type `String`
- `IsStartUp` of type `Boolean`

The result I'm trying to obtain:

| Categorie | IsStartUp |
| --- | --- |
| Bank | false |
| Manifacturing | false |
|  | false |
| Start Up | true |
|  | false |
| Start UP | true |

#### Code I tried

I tried this formula in my [tMap](https://community.talend.com/s/article/tMap-expression-syntax-TCiHW?language=en_US):
`inputrow.Categorie != "Start Up" ? false : true`

But I got this error : `java.lang.NullPointerException`
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AdMGW.png]

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Comparing a constant string to each row should be done like: "constant".equals(rowname.columnname). However, I suspect 1 of 2 things is happening here:1) the row feeding your tMap is not actually called 'inputrow' or 2) you are getting null pointer from a different call somewhere else in the tMap.

Comment: Also, it appears your input values have varied case - you can use equalsIgnoreCase instead of equals for case insensitive comparison.

Comment: @OGmaps you were right, the problem was comming from an other row.